# I cannot figure out why my variable is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I am getting an error in my python code. This is the code

```
binary=[]
bits=int(input("How many bits do you want to have?   >>"))
numOfCombos=2**bits
lenOfPart=numOfCombos/2
x=0
y=0
z=0
while x!=numOfCombos:
    binary.insert(x,[])
    x+=1
x=0
while x!=lenOfPart:
    binary[x].insert(0,"0")
    x+=1
while x!=lenOfPart*2:
    binary[x].insert(0,"1")
    x+=1
x=0
p=0
while x!=bits:
    lenOfPart=lenOfPart/2
    while z!=len(binary)-1:
        while p!=lenOfPart:
            binary[y].insert(len(binary[y]),"0")
            y+=1
            p+=1
        p=0
        while p!=lenOfPart:
            binary[y].insert(len(binary[y]),"1")
            y+=1
            p+=1
        p=0
        z+=1
    y=0
    x+=1

print(numOfCombos)
print(len(binary))
print(binary)
```

I am getting an error that reads

```
How many bits do you want to have?   >>3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/#####/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/binarygen.py", line 24, in <module>
    binary[y].insert(len(binary[y]),"0")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not understand why my variables are not working. I have tested all the things I can think of. If you have any advice, please respond as soon as possible. If you think that the entire program is wrong, please insert a working version into your answer. The purpose of the program is to generate all the possible binary combinations for a given number of bits. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: what ever it is that you are trying to do a double nested loop probably isn't the right way because it doesn't scale at all

Comment: You gave us the whole program (rather than a MCVE), no comments, no design description, and no results of your debugging attempts.  Please don't expect us to reverse-engineer your design with single-letter variable names and no help.

Comment: Could you add a couple examples of inputs & their expected outputs?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an "off by one" error in that loop.  You're trying to add a character to the end of the final element of `binary` (I think).  However, for an input of 3, you use subscript 8 (2**3).  Binary has elements 0-7; subscript 8 is out of bounds.  Perhaps you need

```
        binary[y].insert(len(binary[y])-1,"0")
```

However, I note that you always insert at the end of the list.  Why not simply use `append`?

```
        binary[y].append("0")
```

Better yet, instead of having lists of characters, make each a string:

```
        binary[y] += "0"
```

Also, please note replication capabilities in Python; you don't need those tedious while loops: just add as many 1s or 0s as you need.  Something like:

```
    binary += "0" * (lenOfPart" - p)
```

You can simplify this a lot, once you learn some of the language facilities.

Most of all, figure out at the upper levels what you *really* need to accomplish.  Tell us; you can simplyfy both the problem and the solution.  For instance, as `Delirious Lettuce` showed, you can cut through a lot of grief by searching *first* for built-in capabilities in the `itertools` package.

Comment: Thank you so much. And to answer your question, I use it for readability's sake.

Comment: I believe that you'll find most of your teammates find `append` easier to read.  I hope that you will also see it that way soon enough.  The overhead of specifying the position makes it harder for most programmers.

Comment: I did as you said with changing it to a string. I got the following error. assume that the code is the same except for the inserts are `binary[y]+="0'` or `binary[y]+="1"`. This is the error:
`How many bits do you want to have?   >>3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/broke/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/binarygen.py", line 24, in <module>
    binary[y]+="0"
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Yes, that's what you use for the inserts: a simple string append.  You forgot to list the error.  BTW, I'm about to go off line for the night.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product


def generate_combinations(n):
    return [''.join(p) for p in product('10', repeat=n)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bits = int(input('How many bits do you want to have? '))
    print(generate_combinations(bits))
```

---

```
>>> generate_combinations(1)
['1', '0']
>>> generate_combinations(2)
['11', '10', '01', '00']
>>> generate_combinations(3)
['111', '110', '101', '100', '011', '010', '001', '000']
```

Comment: I am trying to generate all combos based on an input. That does not work for me.

Comment: @JimmyMCJames You haven't given any examples of input and expected output. This code can be easily modified to accept input. If you show a couple of input/output examples it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The loop was stopping at the wrong time. Instead of stopping at `bits` I needed it to stop at `bits-1`.